# links on navigation bar have 100% height as logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put a logo on the same line as the navigation bar with the links floated to the right. I put the image and the `ul` in the same div but how can I have the links stretch the same height as the image? For example, on hover on the links should be highlighted the entire height from the top of the screen to the bottom of the bar/logo. Right now it only highlights the link.

HTML

```
<section id="header">
        <div id="nav">  
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:15%;height:15%">     
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a class="link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="link" href="#about">What we do</a></li>
                <li><a class="link" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="link" href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a class="link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- so float right won't work -->
            <br style="clear:both;" />
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu {
   float: right;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#menu li {
   display: inline;
   vertical-align: center;
   float: left;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#menu li a {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   color: #696969;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
   position: relative;
}

#menu li a:hover {
   color: #004080;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f86u3edt/

For an idea, I'm going for something like this http://michaelaldridge.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope flex will help you.
Here is the updated **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f86u3edt/8/)**

```css
.logo {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu li {
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 align-items: center;
 vertical-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#menu li a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 color: #696969;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
 position: relative;
}

#menu li:hover {
 color: #004080;
 background-color: #aaa;
}

#nav{
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
   <div id="nav"> 
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" alt="logo" style="width:15%;height:15%">  
    <ul id="menu">
     <li><a class="link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a class="link" href="#about">What we do</a></li>
     <li><a class="link" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
     <li><a class="link" href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
     <li><a class="link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- so float right won't work -->
    <br style="clear:both;" />
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: this is all working except the links no longer float right, is there anyway to get this back?

Comment: @johnmurphy updated my answer. check now. its floating to right

Comment: Better you are highlligting the `li` instead of `a`. The reason is if you want to give `.active` to `a` then `a` should be 100% hight as `ul`. but then the text will go up(not center aligned)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/f86u3edt/7/

For the HTML code, I wrap the logo image with a `div` as follows:

```
<div id="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="logo">   
</div>
```

And set its style as:

```
#logo-wrapper {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block; /* inline with the menu div */
}
```

Also, there are some other changes such as setting a height for the navigation bar and some responding height style added for other components.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

just add the following css to your code and will work fine. No drastic change :)

```
 .link{
  line-height:45px
}
```

Comment: Would work unless the text is long enough to break into the second line, right?